# php time from database

Tags: php, time

I use the php `time()` function to insert the time into a database after a user posts on my site.  I store this value as an int.  I believe the `time()` function inputs the number of seconds since like 1970.  I now want to get the current time so I can subtract the two and get the time since the user's post.  I have a two questions regarding this process:

1. Does the time come from the user's computer or somewhere on my server or somewhere else?
2. Is the time function stored as an Int the best way to do this?

Comment: If you need to store dates beyond 1970 and 2038, consider using mySQL's `DATETIME` format instead.

Comment: If the data represents a time I would identify that in the column definition by using a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, not an int. Use SQL functions if you want it returned as seconds since 1970 to your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the time come from the user's
>   computer or somewhere on my server or
>   somewhere else?

- Its based on the server time

> Is the time function stored as an Int
>   the best way to do this?

- As the value returned is int, storing in int is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

the php time function refers to the severs internal time.
you can use timestamp or datetime for storing the time in DB.
From my experience both have a well performance.

Read about differences of time types:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

See the PHP doc on [time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

The `time` function returns an int, so using that and saving it is the simplest and most efficient way.

As PHP is executed on the server the servers time is used. Make sure to set your timezone in your PHP configuration. If you did not, using a verbose log level should warn you about it.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's the server time.
2. It depends on what you are going to do with it. An SQL query for a certain month may be better served by a DATETIME field.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a `DATETIME` column type to store this kind of data. It's pretty easy to recover the values in the way you want (ie: as an UNIX timestamp using MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function, formatted date/time using `DATE_FORMAT`...).

You could in some way override UNIX timpestamp's 1970 limit, for example storing and showing some guy's birthdate prior to 1970. Of couse, if you just store the data in a `DATETIME` column and use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to obtain an int, you did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's best record int in DB and use mktime function to parsing in the page.